# Generate static html files from express server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm, netlify

I've got a nodejs web project running with express-js and ejs. After making it, it appered to me that it can be host throught static html files on Netlify instead of an nodejs app on Heroku. Indeed, the data only change each month so I only have to *build* it once a month. Like that, it will be the best hosting option regarding the price.

Is there a way (npm package, GitHub action, ...) to compile an entire express server + ejs application into a folder of static html/css files in order to be hosted on Netlify ?

I've been looking for a while and I couldn't find anything solving my problem.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through all of the routes, and execute [`app.render`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.render) for each of them, then store results in a file.

Sample code:

```
//express server should be started before this 

const fs = require('fs')

['/', '/about', '/contact'].forEach( path => {

    app.render(path, {
        // optional metadata here
        }, (err, res) =>{
        if (err)
            console.log('Error rendering ' + path, err)
        else {
            fs.writeFile(__dirname + '/public/' + path + '.html', res, function(err, res) {
                if (err)
                    console.log('error saving html file', path, err)
            })
        }
    })

})
```